# How to automatically allow updates of packages only from repositories they were originally installed from

Tags: apt

I am noticing that I have to add more and more PPA repositories to install various smaller packages. I do worry that if any of those repositories get compromised they might publish a "new" ubuntu-base or some other core package with a potentially malicious payload and get it installed over the official package.

Is there a way to configure apt so that it allows updating packages only from repositories the original package came from?

I understand that they could still add malicious payload to the packages they already provide, but I want to limit what they could do.

Comment: You can configure it so that a pattern of package names are installable/updateable from a given origin (see [`man 5 apt_preferences`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/mantic/en/man5/apt_preferences.5.html#description)), but AFAIK there's no way to have it match by whichever origin it was first installed from.

Comment: In the original Debian design for apt, 25 years ago, the human admin had a large role in establishing trust of the various apt sources. That role has not changed. Apt is designed to organize packages and dependencies from all known sources. The human admin is still responsible for curating trustworthy sources and for supervising apt. The possibility of poisoned packages (which have indeed occurred) is another great reason to protect yourself with regular backups.